# min occurs vs group min occurs

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

Good morning,

**The problem:**

I'm trying to create a schema for an input file. I can't get the correct combination of properties to get my test file to validate.

**The input file:**

The file consists of a required header, an optional repeatable group of records, and a required trailer. The file is a list of employees with information about each one. 
The repeated records within the group should be presented in order. Some records in the group are optional and some are not. At most there should be one of each type of record within the repeated group.

like so:

```
header (required)

E1 (required if group is present)
E2 (required if group is present)
E3 (required if group is present)
P1 (optional)
P2 (optional)
P3 (optional)
S1 (optional)

E1  <--- error is here
E2
E3

Trailer (required)
```

The group, E1 through P3, should be in order and can be repeated.

**What I've tried:**

I created a <sequence> and placed E1 through P3 within it.
I set min occurs = 0, max occurs = unbounded on the sequence.

I set min occurs = 1, max occurs = 1 on the required records E1, E2, E3.
I set min occurs = 0, max occurs = 1 on the optional records P1, P2, P3.

**The problem:**

The second occurrence of the group always causes an instance validation fail (Visual Studio 2010). The error message is not helpful: "Unexpected data found"

I'm not clear on the difference between "min occurs" and "group min occurs" on each record.
Is "min occurs" local within the sequence or global?
If I set max occurs = 1 on the E1 record do I get one per file or one per sequence?
The explanation on MSDN is clear as mud.

I tried putting the values in the "group *" properties but still no joy.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

A picture of the schema:

[image]

DPIC is the header, Z1 the trailer. Adding the S1 record seems to cause the failure.
I've looked over the P3 and S1 definitions and they look correct. This is a flat file
schema generated from the MSVC 2010 wizard.

Comment: I've tried rearranging the input to get some clues. The second group of records is not the problem. It only fails if the input doesn't have the optional P1 or P2 records. It fails on the first P3 record following. So I guess the sequence is the problem. How do you specify a sequence with optional records?

Comment: Can you post the XML instead of describing it?

Comment: It's huge and my employer employer might not like it released. I'll see if I can make a representation...

Comment: The sequence E1,E2,E3,P1,P2,P3,S1 validates, but E1,E2,E3,S1 does not. P1-P3 are marked min occurs="0".

Answer (score 0):

The schema does not validate the input file but still generates valid output files. I'm going to consider it closed. Thanks for your help